# Runtime error during Caribbean online judge

Tags: c

Goodnight guys. I've been staying up all night trying to solve this problem  on the [Caribbean Online Judge](http://coj.uci.cu/24h/problem.xhtml?pid=2519), and my solution works very well on my computer, but every time I submit it to the online judge, it gets a runtime error.

Here is the problem:

**Input specification**

First line of input contains the number of test cases T (T <= 500) to follow. Each test case consists of one line containing the postfix expression to be evaluated. This expression is guaranteed to be a valid expression written in postfix consisting of a sequence of non-negative integers and operators +, -, *, all separated by a single space. The length of the each line does not exceed 100 characters. All input, intermediate, and final values will fit in a 32-bit signed integer.

**Output specification**

For each test case, output a line with three spaced-separated integers: the values of the expression when evaluated with a stack, queue, and minimum priority queue, respectively.

**My Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct stack
{
    int * data;
    int size;
    int initialized;

}stack;
void init(stack *);
void stackCopy(stack *, const stack*);
void push(stack *, int);
int findIndexOfMin(stack *);
int findIndexOfMax(stack *);
int minOrMaxPop(stack *, char);
int pop(stack *);
int queuePop(stack *);
int indexOfNextChar(char *, int);
void flush()
{
    char c;
    while(c = getchar())
    {
        if(c == '\n' || c == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int testCases = 0;
    char results[600][110];
    scanf("%d", &testCases);
    flush();
    int count = 0;
    for(count =0; count < testCases; count++)
    {
    memset(results[count], '\0', 109);
    stack numStack = {.data = calloc(1,sizeof(int)), .size = 0, .initialized = 0};
    stack queue = {.data = calloc(1,sizeof(int)), .size = 0, .initialized = 0};
    stack numMinQ = {.data = calloc(1,sizeof(int)), .size = 0, .initialized = 0};
    
    char string[103];
    memset(string, '\0', 102);
    fgets(string, 101, stdin);
    int counter = 0;
    for(counter = 0; counter < strlen(string); counter++)
    {
        if(isdigit(string[counter]))
        {
            int num = atoi(string+counter);
            push(&numStack, num);
            push(&numMinQ, num);
            push(&queue, num);
            counter = indexOfNextChar(string, counter);
        }
        else
        {
            int num1 = 0;
            int num2 = 0;
            switch(string[counter])
            {
                case '+':
                    ;
                    {
                    num1 = pop(&numStack);
                    num2 = pop(&numStack);
                    push(&numStack, num2 + num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    num2 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    push(&numMinQ, num2 + num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = queuePop(&queue);
                    num2 = queuePop(&queue);
                    push(&queue, num2 + num1);
                    }
                break;

                case '-':
                    ;
                    {
                    num1 = pop(&numStack);
                    num2 = pop(&numStack);
                    push(&numStack, num2 - num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    num2 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    push(&numMinQ, num2 - num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = queuePop(&queue);
                    num2 = queuePop(&queue);
                    push(&queue, num2 - num1);
                    }
                break;

                case '*':
                    ;
                    {
                    num1 = pop(&numStack);
                    num2 = pop(&numStack);
                    push(&numStack, num2 * num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    num2 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    push(&numMinQ, num2 * num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = queuePop(&queue);
                    num2 = queuePop(&queue);
                    push(&queue, num2 * num1);
                    }
                break;
                
                case '/':
                    ;
                    {
                    num1 = pop(&numStack);
                    num2 = pop(&numStack);
                    push(&numStack, num2 / num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    num2 = minOrMaxPop(&numMinQ,'s');
                    push(&numMinQ, num2 / num1);
                    }
                    {
                    num1 = queuePop(&queue);
                    num2 = queuePop(&queue);
                    push(&queue, num2 / num1);
                    }
                break;

                default:

                break;

            }
        }
    }
//  sprintf(results[count],"%d %d %d", numStack.data[0], queue.data[0],numMinQ.data[0]);
    printf("%d %d %d", numStack.data[0], queue.data[0],numMinQ.data[0]);
    free(numStack.data);
    free(queue.data);
    free(numMinQ.data);
}
/*
    for(count = 0; count < testCases; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", results[count]);
    }
*/
    return 0;
}
void init(stack * stackToInit)
{
    stackToInit->data = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    stackToInit->size = 1;
    stackToInit->initialized = 1;
}
void push(stack * stackToAdd, int data)
{
    //printf("Stack size %d data: %d\n", stackToAdd->size, data);
    if(!stackToAdd->initialized > 0)
    {
        int * temp = realloc(stackToAdd->data, (stackToAdd->size+1)*sizeof(int));
        if(temp)
        {
            stackToAdd->data = temp;
            stackToAdd->data[stackToAdd->size] = data;
            stackToAdd->size++;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Error reallocating memory!");
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        init(stackToAdd);
        int * temp = realloc(stackToAdd->data, (stackToAdd->size+1)*sizeof(int));
        if(temp)
        {
            stackToAdd->data = temp;
            stackToAdd->data[stackToAdd->size-1] = data;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Error reallocating memory!");
        }


    }
}
void stackCopy(stack * copy, const stack * original)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(counter = 0; counter < original->size; counter++)
    {
        push(copy, original->data[counter]);
    }
}
int findIndexOfMin(stack * queue)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int smallest = INT_MAX;
    int indexOfSmallest = 0;
    for(counter = 0;counter < queue->size; counter++)
    {
        if(queue->data[counter] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = queue->data[counter];
            indexOfSmallest = counter;
        }
    }
    return indexOfSmallest;
}
int findIndexOfMax(stack * queue)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int largest = INT_MIN;
    int indexOfLargest = 0;
    for(counter = 0;counter < queue->size; counter++)
    {
        if(queue->data[counter] > largest)
        {
            largest = queue->data[counter];
            indexOfLargest = counter;
        }
    }
    return indexOfLargest;
}
int minOrMaxPop(stack * queue, char mode)
{
    int index;
    if(mode == 's')
        index = findIndexOfMin(queue);
    if(mode == 'l')
        index = findIndexOfMax(queue);
    int result = queue->data[index];
    if(index == queue->size-1 && queue->size > 1)
    {
        int * temp = realloc(queue->data, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        if(temp)
        {
            queue->data = temp;
            queue->size--;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Error decreasing minimum queue!");
        }
    }
    else if (index == 0 && queue->size > 1)
    {
        memmove(queue->data, queue->data+1, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        int * temp = realloc(queue->data, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        if(temp)
        {
            queue->data = temp;
            queue->size--;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Error decreasing minimum queue!");
        }
    }
    else if(queue->size == 0)
    {

    }
    else if (index == 0)
    {
        memmove(queue->data, queue->data+1, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        int * temp = realloc(queue->data, (queue->size)*sizeof(int));
        if(temp)
        {
            queue->data = temp;
            queue->size--;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("Error decreasing minimum queue!");
        }


    }
    else
    {
        queue->size--;
        memmove(queue->data+index,queue->data+index+1,((queue->size)-index)*sizeof(int)); 
    }
    return result;
}
int pop(stack * numStack)
{
    if(numStack->size > 0)
    {
        int result = numStack->data[numStack->size-1];
        int * temp;
        if(numStack->size == 1)
        {
         temp = realloc(numStack->data, (numStack->size)*sizeof(int));
        }
        else
        {
         temp = realloc(numStack->data, (numStack->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        }
        if(temp)
        {
            numStack->data = temp;
            numStack->size--;
        }
        else
            puts("Error popping from stack!");
        return result;
    }
}
int indexOfNextChar(char * string, int begin)
{
    int counter = begin;
    for(counter = begin; counter < strlen(string); counter++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(string[counter]))
        {
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
int queuePop(stack * queue)
{
    int result = queue->data[0];
    int * temp = NULL;
    temp = realloc(queue->data, (queue->size)*sizeof(int));
    if(queue->size > 1)
    {
        memmove(queue->data, queue->data+1, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
        temp = realloc(queue->data, (queue->size-1)*sizeof(int));
    }
    if(temp)
    {
        queue->data = temp;
        queue->size--;
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Error popping queue!");
    }
    return result;
}
```

**My Input:**
5

7 4 - 5 *

3 2 4 * +

3 4 2 - *

42 7 - 3 * 2 4 + *

5 3 5 - * 11 2 - 1 * -

**Program's Output:**

15 -15 15

11 10 10

6 2 4

630 -412 630

-19 41 3

**Valgrind**

```
==5120== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5120== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5120== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5120== Command: ./postfix
==5120== 
1
1 1 +
==5120== Invalid read of size 2
==5120==    at 0x4C2E9E0: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401520: queuePop (main.c:345)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c4 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid write of size 2
==5120==    at 0x4C2E9E3: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401520: queuePop (main.c:345)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401546: queuePop (main.c:346)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
Error popping queue!
==5120== Invalid read of size 4
==5120==    at 0x4014B0: queuePop (main.c:340)
==5120==    by 0x400B57: main (main.c:80)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B57: main (main.c:80)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid read of size 2
==5120==    at 0x4C2E9E0: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401520: queuePop (main.c:345)
==5120==    by 0x400B57: main (main.c:80)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c4 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid write of size 2
==5120==    at 0x4C2E9E3: memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401520: queuePop (main.c:345)
==5120==    by 0x400B57: main (main.c:80)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x401546: queuePop (main.c:346)
==5120==    by 0x400B57: main (main.c:80)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
Error popping queue!
==5120== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x400EE3: push (main.c:174)
==5120==    by 0x400B73: main (main.c:81)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
Error reallocating memory!
==5120== Invalid read of size 4
==5120==    at 0x400DFF: main (main.c:150)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5120==    at 0x4C2B200: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x400E38: main (main.c:152)
==5120==  Address 0x51d92c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
2 1 2==5120== 
==5120== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5120==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==5120==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 20 frees, 108 bytes allocated
==5120== 
==5120== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5120==    at 0x4C2C29E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5120==    by 0x4014DF: queuePop (main.c:342)
==5120==    by 0x400B45: main (main.c:79)
==5120== 
==5120== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5120==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==5120==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5120== 
==5120== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5120== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 12 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It's a bit odd that the error messages I hardcoded in don't appear when run through a regular terminal, but they appear with Valgrind :/.

I think the problem may be due to some of the reallocs, but I cant figure out why it would work on my computer, but not with the judge

Comment: Seems you only have an array big enough for 100 results, but the spec says there can be up to 500 test cases...?

Comment: @sje397 Changed it to 500 and still no good :/

Comment: You're also reading lines of max length 99, not 100. Probably not the issue either, but I thought I'd point it out. P.S. Check fgets docs - i think it reads n-1 chars.

Comment: Also it looks like your integer input code can only handle single digit numbers.

Comment: I added a bit of extra padding to the relevant arrays, and believe it or not, the input code actually does handle numbers with multiple digits:
900 99 +
= 999 999 999

Comment: Ah yeah, I see. Your initial `calloc` calls will leak, since you later call `init` which does another `calloc`. Also not the issue. FYI you can call `realloc` on a null pointer and it will allocate.

Comment: @sje397 I forgot to mention that changing the array size to 500 did change the message from  "runtime error" to "wrong answer", so I think I'm on the right track now.

Comment: @sje397 I only did the initial calloc calls because valgrind was complaining about me passing around some uninitialized variables, so I tried to get it to be quiet.

Comment: @sje397 I'll add the valgrind error messages so you guys can get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Not sure this is doing what you want: `!stackToAdd->initialized > 0`... You could simplify that by swapping the if blocks and just using `if(stackToAdd->initialized)`. Also it looks like when you first init the stack in your push function, it already has a size of 1, and you increase it by 1 before inserting the new item - leaving an extra item at the end, with a value that's not predictable. That'll mess up your search for minimums etc.

Comment: I mentioned you can `realloc` a null pointer. If you just init your stack with a size of 0 and a null pointer, you can get rid of the whole initializing part of the push function. The same code will work on an empty and non-empty stack - just reallocate, and increment size.

Comment: One last comment: a priority queue is another name for a heap. They are much more efficient than searching the whole list for a min or max [O(log n) worst case, instead of O(n)]. Heaps are super cool and useful and not as complicated as wikipedia might make them seem :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72348/discussion-between-sky-and-sje397).

Answer (score 1):

There may be up to 500 test cases, but your results array is only large enough to hold 100. Change:

```
char results[100][110];
```

to:

```
char results[500][110];
```

Comment: You probably have some further bugs to fix, but this one definitely needs to be taken care of.

Comment: Yes, you're definitely right. I'm thinking some of the reallocs may be causing some problems, so I'll investigate further. Does anything else catch your eye?

Comment: You could probably simplify your stack code a lot - you know how big the stack can get in the worst case, so you could just allocate a fixed maximum size for your stack and not worry about realloc'ing every time you push.

Comment: I'll do that just for the sake of getting this program to work. I'd been hoping to get some practice with dynamic memory allocation, though. I will update with any findings.